# Debuggin function wrapped by triggers - Google Scripts

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-surveys

that's my first time here so I am sorry if I will not follow StackOverflow guidelines to the line.

These days I had to create a pipeline for data collected by a Google Survey to a Google Sheet. The issue is that I am not able to debug in any way the function I wrote which should be triggered on-event formSubmit. The function is the following:

```
function notifyTeam(event) { // should triggered on formSubmit event

  var db = getDB() // custom function to connect to datasheet -> works fine
  var dt = new Date()
  var email = event.responses.getItemResponses()[0] // -> returns error due to event is undefined
  var sap_code = event.responses.getItemResponses()[0] // -> returns error due to event is undefined
```

I would like to know why on Earth the event parameter is undefined while I exactly followed Google Documentation.

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Comment: Question seems to be how this function is called. It seems to be invoked with `undefined` argument. Can you add link to the documentation you've followed?

Answer (score 1):

The fields in an event differ depending on whether the "on form submit" trigger is associated with a form or a spreadsheet. If your script is bound to a spreadsheet, you need to use `event.namedValues` instead of `event.responses`.

See [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) documentation.